# control in ListView.GridViewColumn alignment

Tags: wpf

I have following WPF ListView:

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,53,12,6" 
Name="lvwProperties" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedPropertyItems, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <ListView.View >

                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="130" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Is Mandatory" Width="90"  >

                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                                    <DataTemplate>

                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMandatory, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                                    </DataTemplate>

                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                            </GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

I want to make the CheckBox aligned center in the 2nd GridColumn. Set the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` seems doesn't do the trick. How to achive this in XAML???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To center content in a ListView you need to set ListView.ItemContainerStyle to have a horizontal alignment of Stretch as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,53,12,6" Name="lvwProperties"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedPropertyItems, Mode=TwoWay}"  
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"> 
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
       </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View> 
        <GridView> 
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="130" /> 
            <GridViewColumn Header="Is Mandatory" Width="90"  > 
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> 
                   <DataTemplate> 
                       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMandatory, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
                   </DataTemplate> 
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> 
            </GridViewColumn> 
        </GridView> 
    </ListView.View> 
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well. But why doesn't HorizontalContentAlignment set to 'Center' work?

Comment: @GordonSlysz I think what's happening is there's a "hidden" container inside of each column for the listview items. setting "Center" on your checkbox does center it inside of that container that you can't see, but that container is aligned to the left and is autosized to fit around your checkbox. So it appear that your checkbox is not centering. Setting the ListViewItem's HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch makes this container fill up the entire column, so now when your checkbox is centered it looks the way you expect it to.