# Center text in textblock inside listview wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a problem with TextBlock in my ListView, I can't fill the whole row by textblock and set text on it on the centre. If this is possible in Wpf?

Here is my listView code

```
   <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding cityName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <Run Text=" "/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding strFullName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <Run Text=" "/><Run Text=" "/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding strHouseNo, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <Run Text=" "/>
                             </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Instead of using stackpanel, try use grid or dockpanel.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842168/control-in-listview-gridviewcolumn-alignment)

Comment: For a start a Horizontal Stackpanel laysout in columns in you want rows you need a vertical, second have you tried setting the TextAlignment property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx third if you want advanced control of the formatting you might need to user a Document not a TextBlock https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim if they only have 1 control no point in a panel at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing a number of things wrong here

- you don't need the GridView unless you want a Grid
- you don't need a stackpanel to host a single control
- a horizontal stackpanel arranges items in columns not rows making
  "central alinement" pointless anyway
- you haven't set the listview's HorizontalContentAlignment, this
  defaults to left you need either "Center" or "Stretch"
- you haven't set the TextBlock's TextAlignment

put all of this together and you get this

```
<ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
               <Run Text="{Binding cityName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               <Run Text=" "/>
               <Run Text="{Binding strFullName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               <Run Text=" "/><Run Text=" "/>
               <Run Text="{Binding strHouseNo, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               <Run Text=" "/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Which will centralise your text

i'm not entirely sure you are using Run correctly either but you haven't given enough information to be sure either way, but my suspicion is that you wanted `<LineBreak/>` instead of `<Run Text=" "/>`

OR

if this was an attempt to build a grid then you probably wanted something like this

```
<ListView >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding cityName, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strHouseNo, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I think about first version, run text =" " was to separate texts in one row. Generally I found a solution where someone use grid in list view and it was when I started doing my app. Right now I am trying to neaten code and upgrade it. Arigato MikeT \(^^)/